# Remover partição da tabela

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, database-partitioning

Utilizando a [documentação do MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table-partition-operations.html), criei a partição com base em um campo de ano.

```
ALTER TABLE minhatabela
PARTITION BY HASH (ano_referencia)
PARTITIONS 10
```

Para fazer um possível rollback, como eu droparia essa partição?

Na documentação diz que é pra fazer assim:

```
ALTER TABLE t1 DROP PARTITION p0, p1;
```

Porém, eu não tenho o nome da partição. Utilizando HeidiSQL e visualizando, a tabela a informação fica disponível assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE t1 REMOVE PARTITIONING;
```

---

> [`REMOVE PARTITIONING`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table-partition-operations.html)
>
> [`REMOVE PARTITIONING`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table-partition-operations.html) enables you to remove a table's partitioning without otherwise affecting the table or its data.

Em tradução livre:

> [`REMOVE PARTITIONING`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table-partition-operations.html) possibilita que você remova os particionamentos da tabela sem afetar o restante da tabela ou seus dados.